# OnBindViewHolder for RecyclerView is being called late

Tags: android

I have an EditText where if I reach a certain amount of characters, I add the string to the RecyclerAdapter through an addItem method.

```
@UiThread
public void addItem(String title) {
    logger.v("addTitle: " + title);
    addresses.add(title);
    notifyItemInserted(addresses.size() - 1);
}
```

However, the onBindViewHolder method for the RecyclerAdapter is not being called until I actually dismiss the keyboard. Is there any way I can get around this? For some reason the onBindViewHolder is being called late.

Comment: I think you need to give some more context. Where are you calling addItem()?

Comment: My guess is that the item you're adding is not visible until the keyboard is dismissed, as such, the RecyclerView is free to delay creating and binding the view until it's necessary to actually display the item.

Comment: Good thoughts Brucelet. I'm using the GoogleApiClient to get autocomplete predictions from searching. This includes two methods: one is calling getFilter() which then calls getAutocomplete with a query. getAutocomplete then returns five AutocompletePrediction objects. As soon as I get this list from getAutocomplete, I call addItem for each Prediction object in the getFilter()